# Calculate Container's Height After The Font File Loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, font-face

Styling web with a non-standard font using `@font-face` requires the browser to first download the font file (just like it downloads other assets e.g. CSS, JavaScripts, etc.) before the real rendition happens.

This introduces a problem on Chrome (v16.0.912.63) and Safari (v5.1.2) when jQuery `.height()` tries to calculate its container's height. *The height calculated is **before** the font finishes loading*. Consider the following (view: [working example](http://labs.siku-siku.com/experiment/02/)):

```
/* CSS */
h1 {
  font-family: MuseoSlab-500, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  /* MuseoSlab-500 is defined using @font-face. */
}

/* HTML */
<div id="box">
  <h1>This is my long header. What do you think? How about now?</h1>
</div>

/* JavaScript */
$(function() {
  alert("The height of the above <div> = " + $('div#box').height());
});
```

However, Firefox (v8.0.1) is able to calculate the correct height i.e. after the text is rendered using the non-standard font.

The question is whether there is a practical way to tell Chrome, or ideally *all* browsers, to wait until the text is rendered using the intended font before doing the calculation.

Using `$(window).load()` works but that implies waiting for e.g. all images to finish loading as well; it slows down so much.

Answer (score 3):

I think that `$(window).load()` is the only way to handle what you are talking about. If you page is loading too slowly, perhaps you need to optimize your images, or even load them after the page loads.

Answer (score 3):

you can try to use the webfont loader provided by google

http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader.html#Events

When you handle webfonts with this method, you can specify some javascript callbacks: in your case you need to specify the `fontActive` callback

> *fontactive(fontFamily, fontDescription)*
>
> Called when each requested web font has finished loading. The fontFamily parameter is the name of the font family, and fontDescription represents the style and weight of the font.

Note that you can load webfonts from any site, non necessarily from google, as clearly explained in that page

> In addition to the google, typekit, ascender and monotype options, there is also a custom module that can load a stylesheet from any web-font provider.

Comment: In case you've used it before, can it load a local stylesheet in which the `@font-face` is specified? You mentioned something about loading a stylesheet from any provider, but I wasn't sure if it'd work on a local stylesheet.